# Is this a glitch in The Sims 2?

Tags: the-sims-2

You can buy a Bowling Alley object that resells for more than you buy it for - letting you continuously buy and resell it for boatloads of cash.

Is this a well known glitch? Or is it just me? Are there any other objects that do this?

Comment: What's the exact name of the item in question?

Comment: Yes.  Tell me! I wantz money.

Comment: This is a common gameplay mechanic in The Sims series. Additionally, grand pianos, sculptures, and other random things (like snow in The Sims Vacation) sell for more than their buy price. The longer you own them, the more they're worth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as instantly? Not really, but some pieces of art tend to increase in value over time.

Comment: randomly, up OR down

Answer (score 6):

Objects in The Sims 2 are assigned a "depreciation" value. It's been a while since I looked at the internal code of the game; but if I remember correctly:

The "depreciation value" is between -100 and 100. An object with a 100 depreciation value will lose 100% of it's value over the period of one day (within the game). The average depreciation value is about 10%; which is why objects usually lose monetary value over time. (10% per day, compounded)

Some objects have a negative depreciation value. For example; "-25% depreciation" will cause the object to gain 25% in value each day. Most objects with negative values are artwork/sculptures, which seems logical (as these items typically increase in value in real life). In a few instances; such as the bowling alley, they do gain value due to an error in the objects code. At a guess, I would imagine the programmer entered a negative value by accident.